# i want to draw 100 line in same time not line then line by using

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics

not line after line by using for i as integer=0 to 100 draw

or timer to draw Graphic.Drawline(pens.black,e.x,e.y,0,0)

or write 100 line in code for draw

```
Private Sub Pic_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Pic.MouseMove

Dim graphic as Graphic= pic.creategraphic

graphic.drawline(pens.black,e.x+10,e.y+1,0+a,0+b)

graphic.drawline(pens.black,e.x+20,e.y+2,0+a,0+b)

graphic.drawline(pens.black,e.x+30,e.y+3,0+a,0+b)

graphic.drawline(pens.black,e.x+40,e.y+4,0+a,0+b)

'ec......

End sub
```

i hope to find method to draw amount of line in same time

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't even think it's possible. You could write the lines in a buffer and then draw the buffer on screen.

Comment: because i want to make scale or edit in 2d and i didnt no other method

Comment: and when i make redraw by restore it in txt show drawing fast and other method take 10 min to redraw shape

Comment: Is it always 100?  could you just use an image instead?

Comment: 100 line min but 
Visual Vincent answer it, thanks i forget to use this method i usualy put it in timer not in button Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think doing it at the EXACT same time is possible, but using a loop should draw them so that it looked like they were drawn at the same time.

```
Dim z As Integer
For z = 0 To 100
    graphic.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.x+(z * 10), e.y+z, 0+a, 0+b)
Next
```

And drawing many lines whenever the mouse moves inside it will cause much lag.

Comment: ok ok i know this method but if u typing 100 line on mouse move graphic not equal loop method i want to draw 100 line from listbox or txt same 100 line on code

Comment: maybe it will work on timer to restore from txt or lst i will try it and hope to reduce time of redraw

Comment: thx it is working thx very much      i made my graphic under lst count   into loop then loop make graphic fast

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating an off-screen bitmap to buffer your drawing.  Draw all you lines to that bitmap.  After you are done, draw the entire bitmap to the screen.  This should make them show up all at once and you can do any kind of transform you want, such as scaling, translation, or rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a relatively old question, but I found it searching for something else. Seeing how none of the answers give a proper answer, I'll answer this in case someone else comes looking for answers.

I assume the problem is flickering that you see when the lines are being drawn one by one. A way to solve this is to use **Double buffering**. I suggest you use PictureBox, as it has double buffering enabled as default, but if you're drawing directly onto the form, set `Me.DoubleBuffered() = true` in Form_Load event.

If flickering is not the issue and you just want to draw all the lines at the same time, use `g.DrawLines()` instead of `g.DrawLine()`. All you have to do is to store line points into a point array in your for loop and then pass that array to the drawing method. I am not sure though if this method actually draws them all at the same time, or it simply does one-by-one, but is something to look into.

Answer (score -2):

One way you can do it is to use `.SuspendLayout()` then draw all the lines, then use `.ResumeLayout()` and they will all appear at the same time.

Comment: GDI drawing is done immediately, it isn't affected by layout.